# How to go back to specific line of code when the user input a wrong answer?

Tags: c++

I am making a program that if the user enters wrong operation it will ask again to enter the correct one. But when the user entered wrong it doesn't go back to ask for the correct operation.  Here is my code:

```
do
{
    cout << "Choose Operation to be Used: \n"
         << "   +   --- Addition  \n"
         << "   -   --- Subtraction   \n"
         << "   *   --- Multiplication   \n"
         << "   /   --- Division   \n"
         << "   %   --- Remainder   \n";
    cout << "Answer: ";
    cin >> operation[size];
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    switch (operation[size])
    {
    case '+':
        result[size] = add(num1[size], num2[size]);
        cout << result[size];
        break;
    case '-':
        result[size] = subtract(num1[size], num2[size]);
        break;
    case '*':
        result[size] = multiply(num1[size], num2[size]);
        break;
    case '/':
        if (num2[size] == 0)
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "ANY NUMBER DIVIDED BY ZERO IS: UNDEFINED.\n\n";
            continue;
        }
        result[size] = divide(num1[size], num2[size]);
        break;
    case '%':
        result[size] = remainder(num1[size], num2[size]);
        break;

    default:
        system("cls");
        cout << "PLEASE ENTER A VALID OPERATION.\n\n";
        cout << "First Number: " << num1[size] << endl;
        cout << "Second Number: " << num2[size] << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
} while (!(operation[size]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the value of  `operation[size]` to 0 in your default case:

```
default:
    operation[size] = 0;
    system("cls");
    cout << "PLEASE ENTER A VALID OPERATION.\n\n";         
    cout << endl;
```

Here is a [Live sample](https://onlinegdb.com/SyrPeKCmU)

The code in this link is what you can call a [minimal reproducible example](http://How%20to%20create%20a%20Minimal,%20Reproducible%20Example), for future reference, this is an example of code you should present in a question, if it's runnable on copy/paste it's easier to provide an answer.

Comment: Actually, in my program if the user wants to end it, it will ask if the user want to view history of the equation the user entered that is why I used an array for it. BTW Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: @newbie it makes sense then, but are you initializing size at 0 and incrementing it in each iteration? If not the array will be overwriten in the same position.

Comment: i have set the size to 1 and if the user wants to try again I put an incerement in size so that the data will be stored and the program works fine now

Comment: @newbie, BTW if one of the answers adresses your question correctly, don't forget to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @newbie, Ok then, looks like you got it covered.

Comment: oh okay BTW thanks a lot, I am now learning  pointers. And I'm still confused on how to use it

Comment: @newbie, it's a process, it's always a bit confusing in the beggining... I've been there. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Clear `operation[size]` in `default:` branch in such a way that

```
!(operation[size])
```

will evaluate to `true`

You may do it by

```
default:
  operation[size] = 0;
```

Wrong answers are still non-zero chars which cause `operation[size]` evaluate to `true` and their negations to `false` and this is why loop ends.

But for having things clear you may add a `validAnswerProvided` boolean and set it true in non-default branches only:

```
bool validAnswerProvided = false;
do {
  // ...
  case '/':
     validAnswerProvided = true;
     // ...
  default:
     // ...
} while (!validAnswerProvided);
```

Comment: uhm I,m confused, there is no operation[size] in default

Comment: I've updated answer with exact code how to clear `operation[size]`. Have fun with programming learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the `do-while` is almost useless in your code. The evaluation at the end of it should be changed.

One recommended way is to add a statement `operation[size] = '\0'` in `default:` branch, so the `!operation[size]` will be set to false.

Comment: can i ask what is the meangin of  '\0' ?

Comment: @newbie the `'\0'` is `'00000000'` in its binary representation. C-style strings use it as a termination sign of strings. as you know that the numeric value 0 is false, that's why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are breaking the loop whenever the user inputs a valid input and want to go again for invalid input, try using continue in your default block.

```
while(true)
{
    //Rest of the Statements
    switch(operations[size])
    {
        //Rest of the code
     default:
        system("cls");
        cout << "PLEASE ENTER A VALID OPERATION.\n\n";
        cout << "First Number: " << num1[size] << endl;
        cout << "Second Number: " << num2[size] << endl;
        cout << endl;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to do extra work when things can be so simple.

---

```
int main() {
    char answer;
scan:
    cout << "Choose Operation to be Used: \n"
         << "   +   --- Addition  \n"
         << "   -   --- Subtraction   \n"
         << "   *   --- Multiplication   \n"
         << "   /   --- Division   \n"
         << "   %   --- Remainder   \n";
    cout << "Answer: ";
    cin >> answer;
    cout << endl << endl;
    switch (answer) {
        case '+':
            cout << "Case is +" << endl;
            break;
        case '-':
            cout << "Case is -" << endl;
            break;
        case '*':
            cout << "Case is *" << endl;
            break;
        case '/':
            cout << "Case is /" << endl;
            break;
        case '%':
            cout << "Case is %" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            goto scan;
    }
    return 0;
}
```